# In Angular 2+, should all Services be located inside the CoreModule?

Tags: angular

In Angular 2+ style guide and many other references, I see that all Angular Services which are singleton should be located inside the CoreModule as a best practice.

If it is not located in CoreModule then the service can be made again in the child injector when a module is lazily loaded. This implies that Services that are not singleton should not be located inside the CoreModule. But I am new to Angular and almost all of the Services are made in singleton so far. I can't think of a concrete example in which Services are not made in singleton.

Is non-singleton Services possible which should not be included inside the CoreModule but rather in different place? or should Services always be made singleton and non-singleton Services should be avoided even when possible?

Comment: Your choice of singleton (or not) should be intentional - there is no one rule that fits all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are perfectly fine examples of services that are not singletons.

Many components communicate with descendant components, sibling components or components added by the router using shared services.
If you have a dropdown component that needs to communicate with the items in the dropdown list, you'll have a service instance for every dropdown instance. One shared service for all dropdowns would probably mess up their behavior.

If you have an admin page in a lazy loaded module, you probably don't want to share some services with the customer part, because there is functionality that is specific to the admin page and only required when an admin user is logged in and navigates to that page.

The same might be true for an app that can be split into several modules where not every user loads every module every time.